# best way to attach properties of an object to another object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there an easy way to copy the properties of one object into another object.

for example

```
var a = {
  afunc: function(bla) {
    alert('hello ' + bla);
  },
  avalue: 'aaa'
};

var b = {
  bfunc: function(blb) {
    alert('hi ' +blb);
  },
  bvalue: 'bbb'
};

magically_copy_a_to_b(a,b);
b.afunc('world');
```

should print hello world

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You have `var` statements inside an object literal, and using `=` instead of `:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`underscore.js`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend) which has a built-in `extend` function:

```
_.extend(b, a); // merge a into b
```

Then you can do:

```
b.afunc('hello');
```

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate through the properties of a, then set the properties at b. Note: Objects are passed by reference, and *not* copied.

Copying:

- Numbers, strings, booleans - COPIED
- Arrays: Use `copiedArray = array.slice()` to copy Array `array`
- Simple functions (which do not refer to the scope, such as in your example):
  `copiedFunc = eval(originalFunc.toString())`

```
function magically_copy_a_to_b(a,b){
    for(var prop in a){
        /* Example: copying all string properties*/
        if(typeof prop[a] == "string"){
            b[prop] = prop[a];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are making a lot of confusion, anyway i corrected your objects (no var and use :), and this works by enumerating the properties of one object and adding them to the other (avoiding the prototype chain)

```
function magically_copy_a_to_b(org, dest){
    for (var prop in org){
       if (org.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            dest[prop] = org[prop];
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
var a = {
  afunc: function(bla) {
    alert('hello ' + bla);
  },
  avalue: 'aaa'
};

var b = {
  bfunc: function(blb) {
    alert('hi ' +blb);
  },
  bvalue: 'bbb'
};

b = magically_copy_a_to_b(a,b);


b.afunc('world');
```

Answer (score 0):

This method permanently adds the properties of a json object to another. Because JS is a scripting language, the "eval" function can save the day with a shorter code! Finally, I'm using json because in the "for (var obj1 in obj2)" it returns every keys defined into obj1, and it is basically more funny to deal with json in a bigger code than with a simple array. For example, it's really easy to sort an array of json objects, and you don't have to use the evil "i" to get something into it.

```
function magically_copy_properties(jsonFrom,jsonTo) {
    for (var key in jsonFrom) {
        eval([
            "jsonTo.",key,"=jsonFrom.",key
        ].join(""));
    }
}

var a = {
   "a1": function() {
       return "hello";
   },
   "a2": function() {
       return "hey";
   },
   "aSpace": function() {
       return " ";
   }
}

var b = {
   "b1": function() {
       return "ho";
   },
   "b2": function() {
       return "world";
   }
}

magically_copy_properties(a,b);
alert(b.a1() + b.aSpace() + b.b2());
```